# Deserialize JSON to Java objects with inheritance?

Tags: java, json, inheritance, gson

I need to deserialize the following:

```
{
    "name": "library",
    "contains": [
        {
            "name: "office", 
            "contains": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Home",
            "contains":[{
                "name": "Shelf", 
                "contains" : []
            }]
       }]
}
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class Container
{
     String containerName;
}
Public class Contains extends Container {
    @SerializedName("contains")
    @Expose
    private List<Container> contains;
}
```

How is it that when I run my code, I am hoping to get a contains object to run my methods it won't get me them. But I get a container object and can't run my methods from within my Contains class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need inheritance here. Just use `Gson.fromJson()`.

Object class

```
public class Container {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("contains")
    @Expose
    private List<Container> contains;

    public Container(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        contains = new ArrayList<Container>();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void add(Container c) {
        this.contains.add(c);
    }

    public void setContainerList(List<Container> contains) {
        this.contains = contains;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Container> getContainerList() {
        return this.contains;
    }
}
```

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Container lib = new Container("library");
    Container office = new Container("office");

    Container home = new Container("Home");
    Container shelf = new Container("Shelf");

    home.add(shelf);
    lib.add(office);
    lib.add(home);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // Serialize
    String json = gson.toJson(lib);

    // Deserialize
    Container container = gson.fromJson(json, Container.class);

    System.out.println(container.getName());
    for (Container c : container.getContainerList()) {
        System.out.println("-- " + c.getName());
    }
}
```

Output

```
library
-- office
-- Home
```

Comment: I am adding a Contains object within the list.Like List<Container> contains.add(new Contain(Shelf));

Comment: You don't need `Contains`... A `Container` has a name and a list of things it contains.

Comment: When I deserialize it. The Contain object that I get by doing gson.fromJson(json, Contains.class) returns me objects of container but it's a contains object

Comment: I have another class Book extends container so that I can add it to the list?, I don't think I need that Container class and can just extend it as Contains?

Comment: Since a `Contains` object `extends Container`, it *is* a `Container` object. I don't understand the problem

Comment: Ok, Well When I pull out say office which should contain a list of other Container objects so that I can use the values that they contain I can't because the List is within contains and it returns me a Container so I can't get to the list. Sorry about this I am a noobie haha

Comment: Still, I don't see the reason to subclass the `Container` object

Comment: Thank you, I missed out your first line saying you don't need inheritance! I thought I did! Still confusing but this works as I tested it but thought to make that work as well.